# The text code doesn't add any string data in my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I just practiced my python text functions, but my python text code doesn't append new string data to my text file.
What I should fix to my text code although it should work?

```
f = open("Text.Txt", "a")
f.write("Hello")
f.close
```

Comment: You didn't close the file, so the data you wrote is likely still in a buffer rather than actually being written to disk yet.  `f.close` just references the method, `f.close()` actually calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using f.close, use f.close().

```
f = open("Text.Txt", "a")
f.write("Hello")
f.close()
```